How to use multiple condition left joins in Confluent KSQL query?
I have a KSQL Table with multiple primary keys. I need to create a new stream and perform a LEFT JOIN with the initial Table. However, it appears KSQL does not handle multiple condition LEFT JOINs.
KSQLDB version: 0.29.0
My code is as follows:

Setting offset to earliest

SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest'


Creating the initial stream

CREATE STREAM TEST_INITIAL_STREAM (
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1` STRING,
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2` STRING,
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3` STRING,
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4` STRING,
    `ORDINARY_VALUE1` STRING,
    `ORDINARY_VALUE2` STRING,
    `MY_TIMESTAMP` STRING,
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic1',
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
    PARTITIONS = 3
);


Parsing the timestamp

CREATE STREAM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic2'
) AS SELECT
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4,
    ORDINARY_VALUE1,
    ORDINARY_VALUE2,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP(MY_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED
FROM TEST_INITIAL_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;


Creating the table to hold the maximum timestamp of a unique combination of primary keys

CREATE TABLE TEST_MAX_TIME WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic3', FORMAT = 'JSON'
) AS SELECT
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4,
    MAX(MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP
FROM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM
GROUP BY VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1, VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2, VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3, VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4
EMIT CHANGES;


And finally, I tried to create a filtered stream

CREATE STREAM TEST_FILTERED_STREAM WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic4'
) AS SELECT
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4,
    T1.ORDINARY_VALUE1,
    T1.ORDINARY_VALUE2,
    T1.MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED
FROM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM T1
LEFT JOIN TEST_MAX_TIME T2 ON (
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1 AND
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2 AND
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3 AND
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4
)
WHERE T1.MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED >= T2.MAX_TIMESTAMP
EMIT CHANGES;

However, it appears I cannot do that, with the Unsupported join expression error. What is the appropriate way to perform a left join while having a table with multiple primary keys?
In addition, I tried using one ON conditional and moving the other 3 conditionals to the WHERE clause like so:
CREATE STREAM TEST_FILTERED_STREAM WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic4'
) AS SELECT
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4,
    T1.ORDINARY_VALUE1,
    T1.ORDINARY_VALUE2,
    T1.MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED
FROM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM T1
LEFT JOIN TEST_MAX_TIME T2 ON (
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1
)
WHERE T1.MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED >= T2.MAX_TIMESTAMPAND AND
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2 AND
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3 AND
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4 = T2.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4
EMIT CHANGES;

But this also resulted in an error: Invalid join condition: stream-table joins require to join on the table's primary key .

Looks like you got an answer on reddit?

Correct, I'll post the whole solution as an answer here and link it to the reddit post.

This answer is based on the comment made by vkm80 on reddit.
A proposed workaround is to derive a new column by concatenating primary key column values into a single column. This is how working code would look like:

Setting offset to earliest

SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest'


Creating the initial stream

CREATE STREAM TEST_INITIAL_STREAM (
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1` STRING,
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2` STRING,
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3` STRING,
    `VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4` STRING,
    `ORDINARY_VALUE1` STRING,
    `ORDINARY_VALUE2` STRING,
    `MY_TIMESTAMP` STRING,
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic1',
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
    PARTITIONS = 3
);


Parsing the timestamp (Added COMBINED_KEYS Column)

CREATE STREAM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic2'
) AS SELECT
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3,
    VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4,
    ORDINARY_VALUE1,
    ORDINARY_VALUE2,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP(MY_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED
    CONCAT(VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1, '-', VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2, '-', VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3, '-', VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4) AS COMBINED_KEYS
FROM TEST_INITIAL_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;


Creating the table to hold the maximum timestamp of a unique
combination of primary keys (group by COMBINED_KEYS)

CREATE TABLE TEST_MAX_TIME WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic3', FORMAT = 'JSON'
) AS SELECT
    COMBINED_KEYS,
    MAX(MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP
FROM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM
GROUP BY COMBINED_KEYS
EMIT CHANGES;


And finally, I created a filtered stream

CREATE STREAM TEST_FILTERED_STREAM WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'example-topic4'
) AS SELECT
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY1,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY2,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY3,
    T1.VALUE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY4,
    T1.ORDINARY_VALUE1,
    T1.ORDINARY_VALUE2,
    T1.MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED,
    T1.COMBINED_KEYS
FROM TEST_PARSED_TIMESTAMP_STREAM T1
LEFT JOIN TEST_MAX_TIME T2 ON T1.COMBINED_KEYS = T2.COMBINED_KEYS
WHERE T1.MY_TIMESTAMP_PARSED >= T2.MAX_TIMESTAMP
EMIT CHANGES;

That's it!
